# Unable to use laptop keyboard during installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, keyboard

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a Microsoft Surface laptop to make a dual boot. I've done this many times in the past over the years on different laptops (not the Surface).

No matter what I do, the keyboard doesn't work at all (no keypresses are registered) when trying to install the distro from a bootable USB stick. The trackpad works but not the keys. Everything is fine in Windows. I can't proceed with installation. I've tried booting the live image (keyboard still doesn't work) or going straight to the installer.

Incidentally, this is the same with Mint 20 and Fedora workstation 33.

The laptop only has one USB port, so I can't even try plugging in an external keyboard to continue with the installation.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to do the installation with the on-screen keyboard and the keyboard should be working after the installation. If it still isn't working after the installation, open the additional drivers app and look for a Surface keyboard driver.

Comment: Yep. Managed to install using a usb hub. After installation, I installed the Linux-Surface kernel and the keyboard started working. Thanks.